# '-m' is not recognized as an internal or external command... while updating pip version using -m pip install --upgrade pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pip

I was trying to install a python library using pip install.
My python version: 3.10.4

So, I got this message: "**WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.**"

Now, following the usual procedure(from multiple Youtube videos) used the command "--upgrade pip" in both command prompt and Powershell in the *correct directories*

Got the following errors: '-m' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.    (in command prompt)

Can someone please help with this. Thanks!

Comment: `-m` is an argument to Python. You should run `python -m pip`, not just `-m pip`.

Comment: (note also that `--upgrade pip` isn't itself a complete command; be sure you're showing us what you're doing in enough detail that someone can be sure they're reproducing it accurately).

Comment: Make sure you are using `python -m pip --upgrade pip` It says this in the error message where it lists your python directory.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message already suggests to you that you should use `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`,This command to update pip in your environment.

To install the library, you can use a command like `python -m pip install django`.

For more pip commands, you can refer to [this link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/).

Hope this helps you.